# Triggers to disable and enable foreign key checks

Tags: mysql, jsp, triggers, innodb

I dont know why this wont work, i insert from jsp to database but those triggers i made wont run how i want if anyone know how to solve this hes my hero :)

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER forkey_ON BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
END;  $$
delimiter ;

delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER forkey_OFF after INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
END;  $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: hey did you clarify this problem. I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the answer is...

Setting the `GLOBAL` does not affect current connections.  Setting the `SESSION` may be what you want.  It will apply only to the current connections.  Did you try that?

Comment: no i havnet tried it but  can you make an  example cause im new in databases nad web developing :/ thanks for your time